# sql checkboxes php form

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

Can someone please help me? I wanted to do a little "system" that when I click on my checkbox an SQL statement will be executed.
For example this statement :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = 6;
```

If someone can help me it will be great.

Comment: bizzilion ways to do this, have you tried anything, got any code to share?

Comment: please be more specific with your question, share the code you have so far

Comment: This is not a jobs board. We are not here to "help" you. YOU write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Has you try something? There is a lot of documentation in internet of this. Try it and if you have a problem, come here

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with ajax

**HTML**

```
 <input type='checkbox' onclick'clicked();'>
```

**javascript**+Jquery

```
function clicked(){
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "phpfile.php",
     data:{checked:$("checkboxselector")[0].checked}
   })
}
```

**PHP**

```
//phpfile.php
 $checked = isset($_GET['checked']) && $_GET['checked'] == "true" ?1:0;
 if($checked){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = ''";
    // execute your query
 }
```